# VTP: VLAN is not propagating

Tags: cisco, vlan, packet-tracer, trunk, vtp

This Topology is simple but my VLAN is not propaganting. I'm following this [Tutorial](http://www.freeccnaworkbook.com/workbooks/ccna/configuring-vlan-trunking-protocol-vtp)

[image: Topology]

```
Multilayer Switch0

VTP Version                     : 2
Configuration Revision          : 2
Maximum VLANs supported locally : 1005
Number of existing VLANs        : 6
VTP Operating Mode              : Server
VTP Domain Name                 : College
VTP Pruning Mode                : Disabled
VTP V2 Mode                     : Disabled
VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
MD5 digest                      : 0x8C 0x34 0x21 0x33 0xEF 0xC7 0x4E 0x26 
Configuration last modified by 0.0.0.0 at 3-1-93 00:00:37

VTP Password: 123



Switch1

Switch#sh vtp status
VTP Version                     : 2
Configuration Revision          : 0
Maximum VLANs supported locally : 255
Number of existing VLANs        : 5
VTP Operating Mode              : Client
VTP Domain Name                 : College
VTP Pruning Mode                : Disabled
VTP V2 Mode                     : Disabled
VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
MD5 digest                      : 0xE6 0x2A 0x85 0x14 0x05 0x53 0x1C 0xA1 
Configuration last modified by 0.0.0.0 at 0-0-00 00:00:00

Switch#sh vtp password 
VTP Password: 123
```

What the difference to setting VLAN in Global Mode or using "VLAN Database"?

Comment: Is the link between switches configured as a trunk on both ends?

Comment: Actually, I didn't configure "Trunk Mode".. Is it necessary?

Comment: VTP is "VLAN trunking protocol". Yes, trunks are necessary.

Comment: What is the Trunk Function in this case?  I always associated Trunk with Router-on-stick, because I will use more switch L2

Comment: VTP only propagates on trunks. The easiest thing to do is `switchport mode trunk` on the link interfaces. The mulitlayer switch may need you to set the trunk encapsulation first.

Comment: When you say "encapsulation" is refering about sub-interface?

Comment: No, the trunk encapsulation like `switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q`. Not all Cisco switches require/support this command since they only support 802.1Q encapsulation, but some of the multilayer switches support both 802.1Q and ISL so you must specify before setting the mode to trunk.

Comment: It's working , I only configure Trunk Mode on Switch L2. Can you answer for me accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VTP only propagates on trunks, so you must have a trunk link between the switches.

Comment: one more question,  If I want to create a dhcp pool, where do I need to configure? Switch L2 or L3?

Comment: That is a different question that should be a new question, but, to answer, that should be configured on a layer-3 device.

Answer (score 0):

Switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
no ip address
specify native vlan
Allowed vlans " " 
switchport no negotiate

If you configure both sides of the trunk in this fashion your problems will most likely go away...they call it vlan trunking protocol for a reason ;)